# C# process's exit code always returning Zero while running ADB commands?

Tags: c#, android

I am trying to execute ADB command to check file exists on the device , but the exit code is always returning me Zero irrespective of file exists on the device.

```
    Process process = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

    startInfo.FileName = "adb.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = " shell ls /sdcard/xx.log";

    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

    // Pass in Start Info into process
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;

    // Run Command
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
    //
    Console.WriteLine("\tExit code: " + process.ExitCode);
```

Could some one please help?, thanks in advance

**[Update 1]**:I found some workaround by reading the standard output

```
// Run Command
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
string output = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
if(output.Contains("No such file or directory")) return false;
```

but I want to make it more generic by reading the Exit status

Comment: Exit code 0 means success by default ;)

Comment: Yes, but even when the file is not present on the device, it's returning the exit code as Zero

Comment: Use try/Catch to debug it then, btw what code ar eyou expecting ?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The solutions look like is for unix, as 'echo $?' does not work in windows. I have also tried using %ERRORLEVEL%, which is also returning 0 in case of failure

Comment: Your device and adb binary has to support `shell_v2`, otherwise you could use a command like `adb shell ls /sdcard/xx.log; echo $?` and check the last line for the exit code.